# Math question in regards to functions in the form (1) / ( b ^ c )

Tags: c++, math, interpolation

I've found functions which follow the pattern of 1 / b<sup>c</sup> produce nice curves which can be coupled with interpolation functions really nicely.

The way I use the function is by treating 'c' as the changing value, i.e. the interpolation value between 0 and 1, while varying b for 'sharpness'. I use it to work out an interpolation value between 0 and 1, so generelly the function I use is as such:

```
float interpolationvalue = 1 - 1/pow(100,c);
linearinterpolate( val1, val2, interpolationvalue);
```

Up to this point I've been using a hacked approach to make it 'work' since when interpolation value = 1 the value is very close to but not quite 0.

So I was wondering, is there a function in the form of or one which can reproduce similar curves to the ones produced by 1 / b<sup>c</sup> where at c = 0 result = 1 and c = 1 result = 0.

Or even C = 0, result = 0 and C = 1 result = 1.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, this is a confusing question. I just spent the last 5 minutes trying to decode it. Did you know that `^` operator performs a bit-wise xor? There is no power operator in C++, only the `pow` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interpolation the approach offering the most flexibility is using [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation), in your case quadratic splines would seem sufficient. The wikipedia page is math heavy, but you can find adapted desciptions on google.

Comment: hmm, that's pretty intriguing except it's hard to model a cubic interpolation in a graph. Is there a tool online I could use to visually create and modify a cubiclly interpolated graph?

Comment: I found this http://www.vias.org/simulations/simusoft_spline.html. Once you get what you want, feed the derivatives and other values to the wikipedia page to get the desired equation.

Answer (score 1):

`1 - c ^ b` with small values for `b`? Another option would be to use a cubic polynomial and specifying the slope at 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a similar curve of the form `A - 1 / b^(c + a)`, choosing values of `A` and `a` to match your constraints. So, for `c = 0, result = 1`:

```
1 = A - 1/b^a   =>   A = 1 + 1/b^a
```

and for `c = 1, result = 0`:

```
0 = A - 1/b^(1+a)  =>  A = 1/b^(1+a)
```

Combining these, we can find `a` in terms of `b`:

```
1 + 1/b^a = 1/b^(1+a)
b^(1+a) + b = 1
b * (b^a - 1) = 1
b^a = 1/b - 1
```

So:

```
a = log_b(1/b - 1) = log(1/b - 1) / log(b)
A = 1 + 1/b^a = 1 / (1-b)
```

Answer (score -1):

In real numbers, the ones that mathematician use, no function of the form you specify is ever going to return 0, division can't do that.  (1/x)==0 has no real solutions.  In floating point arithmetic, the poor relation of real arithmetic that computers use, you could write 1/(MAX_FP_VALUE^1) which will give you as close to 0 as you are ever going to get (actually, it might give you a NaN or one of the other odd returns that IEEE 754 allows).

And, as I'm sure you've noticed, 1/(b^0) always returns 1 since b^0 is, by definition of 0-th power, always 1.

So, no function with c = 0 will produce a result of 0.

For c = 1, result = 1, set b = 1

But I guess this is only a partial answer, I'm not terribly sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Regards

Mark

Comment: And now, reading the other response, I'm certain I misunderstood the question.  Please will someone downvote my answer, I can't.

Comment: If you think your answer is wrong, it's better to delete it than leave it to be downvoted.

Comment: No, I think the public humiliation is an essential part of my recovery.